# No gmail print ability

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, printing, gmail

Using Chrome or Firefox. When I log in to gmail and open a message, I see no Print icon, and Print is grayed out in the menu. How do I get them back? I have logged out and logged in to no avail

Comment: Try using your web-browsers in private mode with all the extensions disabled. If this works then there is an extension that is interfering if this doesn't work please add more details like operative system name and version, confirm that your OS have installed the most recent critical updates that the web browsers are updated.

Comment: I have Gmail in Chrome in Windows 10 Pro. Print Icon is light but it works. It darkens when I hover over it.  Maybe fully uninstall Chrome, restart and install Chrome again.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+P (⌘+P on Mac)?